Handle text column with PyTorch
I'm new in ML so question may be stupid.
I have a data set with multiple numeric columns and one text column. Text is just one sentense.
So i want to use all data avaible for classification. But i don't know how to handle mixed dataset numeric+text. Found a lot of examples of text classification but they use text only.
I know how to do in in Catboost: declare text_features option, or turn text into embeddings with Bert model and turn embeddings into numeric columns and use it like any other numeric columns.
But how properly do in in PyTorch?

In pytorch it works the same, you need to embed the text in some way to numerical values such that calculations can be done on the input. You can use simple logic for this, e.g. count how many times a word occurs, or use more advanced methods such as word/sentence embeddings.

I would like to ask about the classification model that u are building in Pytorch used for. Depending upon the Need you would be able to understand the reason and then u can proceed forward with the classification algorithm in machine learning
to understand how to handle multiple mixed datasets
the classification algorithm is a supervised machine-learning algorithm where u train the model on a labeled dataset
example:-

u will have a dataset of cats and dogs and u will train the model
saying that it is cats and dogs so now if u give the picture of a lion
It would say it is a cat because u trained it but if u give a picture of
Human it wouldn't, another type of example is spam identification if
an email is spam or not, this entire classification comes under
Binary Classification, when there is a prediction that has to be done for multi-class then it is called Multi-Class Classification
such as classifying which books come under which category

So understanding these key differences would make you make a better algorithm and I believe that the learning curve for Scikit-Learn is easy compared to PyTorch where pytorch is mainly used for higher advanced machine learning such as building anns, cnns but that's just my opinion based on your comfort try learning about encoding because u use categorical encoding to turn the text into a numeric so that u can then use a classification algorithm.
I think u should try working more on machine learning as there is no need to jump into high-intensive models such as BERT for turning a text into a numeric column.
This can be achieved in PyTorch and sci-kit Learn by calling categorical encoders and I believe you should work from sci-kit learn or tensorflow because Pytorch is heavily made for deep learning and the extensive learning curve of Pytorch is not something I would recommend for a user but here is what u can use in PyTorch for encoding the text

> One-Hot Encoding: PyTorch doesn't have built-in one-hot encoding like
 scikit-learn, but you can implement it manually using torch.scatter.
 It creates one-hot encoded vectors based on class indices and can be
 customized for memory efficiency. You can see an example of this here.
 
> Embedding Layers: PyTorch offers nn.Embedding layers to handle
 high-cardinality categorical variables efficiently. Embedding layers
 map each category to a dense, lower-dimensional vector, capturing
 relationships between categories. This is more memory-efficient than
 one-hot encoding, especially for large datasets.


